# How do I create a second stack in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, nasm

I'm trying to do a two stack sort in assembly. I understand for the first stack you use the system stack; however have no idea how one would implement the second stack.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem, you need to answer three questions: What operations do I need, what does each operation do, and how can I do that?

### What operations do I need?

A stack has two operations: Push and pop.

### What does each operation do?

Let's model our implementation after the system stack. Then this question becomes "what do the `push` and `pop` instructions do?". The `push` instruction decrements the stack pointer and stores its argument at the location it now points to. The `pop` instruction reads the value the stack pointer points to, increments the stack pointer, and returns the read value.

### How can I do that?

Pushing was two steps: Decrementing the stack pointer and storing a value. There are already instructions for just this purpose. The `push` instruction uses `esp` as the stack pointer, but since we are writing our own, we can use whatever we want. We will use `edx`, and assume the value to store is in `eax` (we are storing 4 bytes).

```
sub edx, 4           ; Decrement the stack pointer one position (4 bytes)
mov dword [edx], eax ; Store the value at the new location
```

Popping was three steps: Getting the value, incrementing the stack, and returning the value. We will return the value simply by leaving it in `eax`.

```
mov eax, dword [edx] ; Load the value off of the stack
add edx, 4           ; Increment the stack pointer one position (4 bytes)
; Leave the result in eax to return it
```

Now that we have implementations for both operations, we can use them how we like. Perhaps we want to wrap them in a function by adding code to read the arguments into the registers (if needed) before, and a return after. Or, maybe we just want to insert these directly where we need them, changing registers to suit our needs.

Answer (score 0):

Load everything into the stack and use pointers?

Mov eax,[point1-4] (top of stack down)

mov ebx,[point2-4] (limit of point 1 down)

you usually decrement by 4 because items are stored as dwords

if you mess with the stack start off by storing esp to a DW[stackstore]

mov dword [stak],esp

and return the stored value to esp at the end of your routine

mov esp,[stak]

ret

The stack can be a bit funny and crash a routine unless you keep your foot firmly on its throat